# d3 Bubble chart - update live data

Tags: d3.js

I am using d3 Bubble chart.

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269

In this plugin when i click the circle need to render data for the particular circle content.

I added mycode bellow:

data1:

```
var data1 = '{ "name": "flare", "children": [ { "name": "rcccccccccc", "children": [ { "name": "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrR", "size": 1000 } ] }, { "name": "crcccccccccc", "children": [ { "name": "crrrrrrrrrrrrrrrR", "size": 4116 } ] }, { "name": "c", "children": [ { "name": "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrRc", "children": [ { "name": "CC", "size": 6703 } ] } ] }, { "name": "rccccccccccz", "children": [ { "name": "zrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrR", "size": 6703 } ] } ] }';
```

after click the circle render data2:

```
 var data2 = '{ "name": "flare", "children": [ { "name": "1111111", 
"children": [ { "name": "11111111", "size": 1000 } ] }, { "name": "1111111", "children": [ { "name": "zzzzzzzzzzz", "size": 4116 } ] }, { "name": "c", "children": [ { "name": "zzzzzzzzzzz", "children": [ { "name": "CC", "size": 6703 } ] } ] }, { "name": "zzzzzzzzzzz", "children": [ { "name": "zzzzzzzzzzz", "size": 6703 } ] } ] }';
```

Code:

```
var data1 = JSON.parse(data1);
var data2 = JSON.parse(data2);
console.log(data2)



var diameter = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    color = d3.scale.category20c();
    var diameter = 960, format = d3.format(",d"), color = d3.scale.category20c();

    var bubble = d3.layout.pack().sort(null).size([diameter, diameter]).padding(1.5);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", diameter).attr("height", diameter).attr("class", "bubble");

    update(data1);



    // Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
    function classes(root) {
        var classes = [];

        function recurse(name, node) {
            if (node.children)
                node.children.forEach(function(child) {
                    recurse(node.name, child);
                });
            else
                classes.push({
                    packageName : name,
                    className : node.name,
                    value : node.size
                });
        }

        recurse(null, root);
        return {
            children : classes
        };
    }


    d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");

    function update(root) {

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(bubble.nodes(classes(root)).filter(function(d) {
            return !d.children;
        })).enter().append("g").attr("class", "node").attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

        node.append("title").text(function(d) {
            return d.className + ": " + format(d.value);
        });

        node.append("circle").attr("r", function(d) {
            return d.r;
        }).style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(d.packageName);
        }).on("click", function(d) {
            alert('rl');
            console.log(data2);
            update(data2);

        });
        ;

        node.append("text").attr("dy", ".3em").style("text-anchor", "middle")
        //.text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3);
        });
    }
```

When i Click the circle the new data (data2) need to update in the existing circle.

I added my code in Jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/uXn2p/150/

Answer (score 0):

In the code you did not remove old data when inserting new ones forcing the update.

Here it is a quick working code

```
var data1json = '{ "name": "flare", "children": [ { "name": "rcccccccccc", "children": [ { "name": "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrR", "size": 1000 } ] }, { "name": "crcccccccccc", "children": [ { "name": "crrrrrrrrrrrrrrrR", "size": 4116 } ] }, { "name": "c", "children": [ { "name": "rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrRc", "children": [ { "name": "CC", "size": 6703 } ] } ] }, { "name": "rccccccccccz", "children": [ { "name": "zrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrR", "size": 6703 } ] } ] }';
var data1 = JSON.parse(data1json);
var data2json = '{ "name": "flare2", "children": [ { "name": "test", "children": [ { "name": "11111111", "size": 1000 } ] }, { "name": "test1", "children": [ { "name": "test2", "size": 4116 } ] }, { "name": "test3", "children": [ { "name": "zzzzzzzzzzz", "children": [ { "name": "test4", "size": 6703 } ] } ] }, { "name": "test5", "children": [ { "name": "test6", "size": 6703 } ] } ] }';
var data2 = JSON.parse(data2json);
console.log(data2)
var diameter = 960,
    format = d3.format(",d"),
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .size([diameter, diameter])
    .padding(1.5);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
    .attr("class", "bubble");

    update(data1);
// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
function classes(root) {
  var classes = [];
  function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
    else classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
  }

  recurse(null, root);
  return {children: classes};
}

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", diameter + "px");
function update (data){
  svg.selectAll(".node").remove();
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(classes(data))
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.className + ": " + format(d.value); });
  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.packageName); })
      .on("click", function(d) {
      alert('update');
      console.log(data2);
      update(data2);
        });
  node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      //.text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });
}
```

Here it is the corresponding Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXn2p/151/

Comment: The library you refer to make usage of transitions and delay. Please read here a tutorial http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/ Quick sample code: node.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .transition().delay(100)
      .text(function(d) { return d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3); });